# Foreign key constraint danger - information leakage?

Tags: databases, data-leakage

Suppose we have an SQL database.
Suppose we have a user D who has no read access to some table named EMP (employees).

Suppose we allow him to create a table with a foreign key regarding EMP table. Is the danger here that when inserting into his table, by having failed/succeeded to insert D can infer what keys are absent/present in EMP ?

Also, say we allow D to read from EMP and he can also define a foreign key in his new table regarding EMP. Is the danger still the same only that others who can read D's table can try inserting and inferring ? Because basically D can copy EMP to his table because he can read EMP. So why does the foreign key matter if D can read EMP and is able to copy it anyway ?

How does the foreign key add to the security problem if having read access on EMP means you know all of EMP's entries ?

Comment: The original question didn't say anything about EMP. I assume it's a table with employees data (id as primary key, name, salary) and someone wants that info to remain private. But that's my guess, the question is rather general.

Comment: Normally keys aren't supposed to contain meaningful information.  Some people violate this DB design principle, and use a name as a key, i.e. johnTJohnson01011984.  The only real danger in leaking the presence of a key is if it contains real information.  i.e. if it's an increasing integer, it might give away roughly how many employees you've had.

Comment: @SteveSether But then, what would be the extra danger of giving D read access on EMP + foreign key right. If D has read on EMP he can copy EMP anyway so why does the foreign key add to the danger ?

Comment: Is it because if D doesn't cooperate (does not copy EMP into his table) then others who can read his own table can infer the keys of EMP by failing/succeeding to insert into D's table ?

Comment: Presumably the employee table has more information that just a key.  It's sort of hard to make generalizations here without real information.  Is this some kind of school homework?

Comment: Yes, and that is basically all the info given. It's quite general.

Comment: But how could you possibly infer the other info from EMP if all you can "play" with is the foreign key ? Say you are a user who can only read from D's table and not from EMP, and say D doesn't care to copy all of EMP into his table

Comment: This is the general problem with contrived examples that are created in academia for homework problems.  Academics have a penchant for thinking so abstractly, that they don't even recognize that they've missed important details.  It's also one of the reasons why asking HW problems here is frowned upon.  Go ask your professor about what he/she was actually thinking about, rather than trying to make guesses based on limited information.

Comment: Yes, i tend to agree with you...